# Insert image or text into div on a static webpage by clicking on bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a table in bootstrap that can be edited online by users without using a database backend.

Please see a preview of my page at https://preview.c9users.io/tomheaps/whiteboard/index.html?_c9_id=livepreview3&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io#

You will see that I have managed to insert a dropdown menu which appears if you **click on the table cell directly under the 'Diet' column header**. Is there any way using jquery that you can click on an item from the menu list to insert a specific image or text into the div from which the dropdown originates (i.e. into the table cell that you clicked on).

Ideally I want the text or image that the user has inserted to remain in that div until it is changed, even if somebody views the page on a different computer - not sure if this is possible in a static webpage without using a database back end.

My javascript skills are non-existent and can't find anything similar after hours of trawling the web so any scripts to enable this would be very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

You need a database to show any data which needs to appear in a new computer.
Anything you insert by js in your current DOM document shows just for the current user.
You have to store the data in a remote server in order to allow new users to see its.

Comment: Thanks for replying, is there no way that the html of the page you are viewing can be altered using jquery to reflect any changes you make?

Comment: I'm not sure about your question. The jquery changes the html itself, yes. It changes the elements in the current page. But to change what other user is viewing (in a remote computer) you need to build a server-side application to apply the changes every time someone opens the page.

Comment: I meant is it possible for jquery to dynamically alter the html on the page stored on the server so that anybody else viewing the page will see the changes you have made??